# Dropzone dynamically allow duplicates images

Tags: javascript, dropzone

Using dropzone Js i have a checkbox  what i want to do is allow the user to select whether to allow duplicates or not  I need to change this property **preventDuplicates** from true to false  and vice versa

I'm tried to google my error but I cant find any relevant answers

My Options

```
        var uploadoptions = { 
            url: '{{URL('photographer/postEventImages') }}',
            
            params: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                "event_id": $("#event_id").val(),
                "folder_id": $("#folder_id").val(),
            },
            uploadMultiple: false,
            thumbnailWidth: 80,
            thumbnailHeight: 80,
            parallelUploads: 12,
            maxFiles: max_files,
            acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/jpg",
            previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
            dictDuplicateFile: "Duplicate Files Cannot Be Uploaded",

            preventDuplicates: true,
            //autoQueue: false,
            previewsContainer: 
            clickable: ".fileinput-button",
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            createImageThumbnails: true,// Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
            success: function (file, response) {
                file.previewElement.querySelector(".progress-bar").classList.remove('bg-warning');
                file.previewElement.querySelector(".progress-bar").classList.add('bg-success')
            }
        };
```

My initialization

```
       var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#previews', uploadoptions);

            $('#startUpload').click(function(){
                  myDropzone.processQueue()
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

so I solved it I just had to take out the property
and add this

```
     $('#duplicates').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
          myDropzone.options.preventDuplicates = false;
        }else{
             myDropzone.options.preventDuplicates = true;
        }
      
    })
```